# Is this naive equals, hashcode OK?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have a class representing DB-Entries with a unique Id attribute.
Is is OK to implement the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods only based on this attribute

```
  @Override public int hashCode()
  { return id;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if (this == obj)                  return true;
    if (obj == null)                  return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    Task other = (Task) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
      return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes. If all the ids are small consecutive integers, you could get better performance from big collections by using a function which distributed the bits more widely throughout the available 32 bits. But this should work find otherwise.

Comment: Doesn't `HashMap` go out of its way to mangle the hash code it gets from the object?

Comment: @NPE [Yeah, it does.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#256)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with this code. However, there are some questions you might wish to ponder:

- Can you ever have more than one object with the same `id`?
- Will the class ever be subclassed?

Comment: thx, * more objects with the same id:yes, but they are equal *class is final

Answer (score 0):

You said in your comments that the class is final, then I would suggest equals design like in Integer.equals

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```